# Autoscrolling a table

Tags: javascript, scroll

I'm working on a table which, depending on user data, may be too wide to fit on the display, so we made it "overflow: auto;".

I want to be able to automatically scroll the table so that a certain named cell -- say: ('cell_' + row + '_' + col) is visible.

How do I get this to happen? I've seen a couple of suggestions here involving jQuery but couldn't get them to do anything.

I don't need smooth animation, in fact I'd rather there wasn't any as I find it's a distraction for the users.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this](https://jsfiddle.net/Arg0n/doypbd7e/) fiddle:

JavaScript

```
var container = $(".narrow");
container.scrollTop(0);
container.scrollLeft(0);
container.scrollTop($("#cell_3_3").offset().top - container.offset().top);
container.scrollLeft($("#cell_3_3").offset().left - container.offset().left);
```

HTML

```
<div class="narrow">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td id="cell_1_1">1. Content ...</td>
      .....
    </tr>
    .....
  </table>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.narrow {
  max-width: 100px;
  max-height: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

**UPDATE 1**

New [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Arg0n/doypbd7e/3/) to demonstrate better. Looping through all cells.

Comment: Thanks, that is just what I was after.

Comment: @NickLevine Please upvote and mark as answer if this helped you.